# junit with spring and mybatis

Tags: spring, junit, mybatis

I'm new to junit and TDD.

I've just made my first test case.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-beans/spring-cms-root.xml"})
public class MemberServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    MemberService memberService;

    @Test
    public void testGetMemberById() {
        Member member = memberService.getMemberById("testid");
        assertTrue(member != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMemberBySeq() {
        Member member = memberService.getMemberBySeq(1);
        assertTrue(member != null);
    }
}
```

But this Test Class gave me this error below upon running junit test.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.tource.cms.member.MemberService.getMemberById
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:672)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:507)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:500)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.setupCommandType(MapperMethod.java:240)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:71)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:39)
    at $Proxy18.getMemberById(Unknown Source)
    at com.tource.cms.member.MemberServiceImplTest.testGetMemberById(MemberServiceImplTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

So I changed my test class little as below.

```
public class MemberServiceImplTest {

    MemberService memberService;

    public MemberServiceImplTest() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans/spring-cms-root.xml");
        memberService = ctx.getBean("memberServiceImpl", MemberServiceImpl.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMemberById() {
        Member member = memberService.getMemberById("testid");
        assertTrue(member != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMemberBySeq() {
        Member member = memberService.getMemberBySeq(1);
        assertTrue(member != null);
    }
}
```

And this works well. anyone has idea why it works or not?

I don't have any idea about difference between two classes.

Comment: Sounds like your mybatis mapping/config files are not being loaded, although you haven't provided many details. (1) Where are your configs within your project's directory structure (e.g. `src/main/resources`)? (2) How do you build the project (e.g. Maven?)? (3) How is the working example launched, since you removed the `@RunWith` annotation. (4) In the broken example, what happens if you add `@Qualifier("memberServiceImpl")` to your `memberService` declaration just below `@Autowired`? FYI instead of `assertTrue(member != null)`, you should `assertNotNull(member)`.

Comment: @jtoberon wow!!!, you solved it. after configuring \@Qualifier as you commented, everything works. thank you

Comment: Cool. That was a shot in the dark. I moved the suggestion to an answer so that you can accept it for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your mybatis mapping/config files are not being loaded, or your bean is not being auto-wired properly. In the broken example, try adding @Qualifier("memberServiceImpl") to your memberService declaration just below @Autowired.

FYI since you say you're new to unit testing, instead of assertTrue(member != null), you should assertNotNull(member). In the event that your assert fails, this will produce a slightly better error message.